# XML / Java Simple Text Search; js or java approach

Tags: java, javascript, extjs, xml-parsing

I have some XML coming from a remote server that I need to implement in a filtered/searchable way for a web form.

I know of quite a few ways to approach the problem.. extJS provides a nice livesearch api that would work nicely but I'm a version behind.. So I though maybe I could accomplish this easier with java or other js?

Here is what my XML looks like..

```
<SearchText> 
   <applicationname>Application1</applicationname>
   <searchvalue>some search term</searchvalue> 
</SearchText>    
<SearchText> 
   <applicationname>VIM Application1</applicationname>
   <searchvalue>some other search term</searchvalue> 
</SearchText>    
<SearchText> 
   <applicationname>VIM Application1</applicationname>
   <searchvalue>more search terms</searchvalue> 
</SearchText>
```

Ultimately I'm doing a lookup into this structure by "applicationname" and I want to search all the "searchvalues" for that set of application and return the application name if the search term exists there -

JavaBeans of this structure exist as well.. So I'm really just looking for the simplest approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about E4X in Rhino ? Or even Plain old [XSLT/XPATH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) ?